# How to set ps as shortcut to open powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables

The question says it all. I want to learn and use powershell as my go to terminal in windows and I want powershell to open if I type `Win+R` followed by `ps`. Much like how `cmd` is used to open command prompt.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/193000/running-programs-by-typing-some-alias-in-windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a symbolic link (similar to a shortcut) to Powershell with any name you want.

This will create one called `ps.exe` in the powershell folder, this folder is already listed in `PATH` so will enable you to run `ps` from the RUN box like you want.

```
mklink %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ps.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Be sure to run the command in an elevated command prompt.

Comment: Great! I modified your simbolic link. Now I can call **PowerShell 7** from the windows explorer by typing "ps" in the Adress bar (after installing pwsh7):
`mklink "%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ps.exe" "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe"`

Answer (score 1):

The "default" command for opening PowerShell is `powershell`. If you want to make it `ps`, your best bet is to create a batch file named `ps.bat` containing the single line

```
@powershell %*
```

and place it in one of the directories named in your system `PATH` variable.